# Multi-step task approval workflow - SharePoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, task-list, workflow-tasks-list

I have made a multi-step task approval workflow in SharePoint designer 2013.
On list item creation, workflow assigns the task to user1, 
when user1 approves it, the task is created for the user2, 
and when user2 approves it, the task is created for the user3.

All three users redirect to the same page.

Now what I am trying to do is, I want to show only selected columns to the user.
Let's say, user 1 will see the only column1.
user 2 will see the only column2.
user 3 will see the only column3.

**How can I show only specific columns to different users on the same page? Or is there any alternative to achieve the same.?**

Comment: Create view as per logged in user for view and for fields in form you need to user jquery to hide fields as per assigned user and set target audience on view.

Comment: Is not it possible without JQuery.? Is not it possible OOTB.? Because this does not seems possible, as we are redirecting all the users on the edit form of the task list.

Comment: When u redirect user on the edit page u get item ID from that ID you get assigned user name or workflow status so on basis of that u can show or hide form fields other then you have to implement custom form which need more efforts as compare to other.